# android notification not firing

Tags: android, notifications

I've been searching for a reason why my notification isn't being displayed in the notification bar and can't seem to grasp why not.. Does anyone see something needing to be done in this code?

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(DisplayNotification.this)
                                                .setContentTitle("Due")
                                                .setContentText("Do it fast!")
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.book);

            //---100ms delay, vibrate for 250ms, pause for 100 ms and
            // then vibrate for 500ms---
            notif.setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 250, 100, 500});        
            nm.notify(notifID, notif.build());

    }
```

Comment: Where is the notification intent and the `PendingIntent` ? If you do not want any activity to be triggered when the notification is tapped, use an empty `Intent` as the content intent - `PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0)`

Comment: If there's a problem with the notification object, the notification manager will usually complain in the log. Does `adb logcat` show anything interesting when this code is run?